# How to retrieve injected data by @include as array?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I include one partial layout by this code:

```
@include("someview", ["name"=>"the_name", "family" =>"the_family"])
```

inside of this partial view, I need to access this data as an array not variable because of sending data to a localization string as a parameter.

For example I need access to `name` by `$arr['name']` not `$name`.

Is there any way to access injected data container itself? Like ASP.NET MVC which has a `@model` variable that contains all passed data to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@include("someview", ['arr' => ["name"=>"the_name", "family" =>"the_family"]])
```

You can also convert object data to arrays like so:

```
@include("someview", ['arr' => (array) $yourObject])
```

To get the variables that are injected into the views, you should be able to use:

```
{{ get_defined_vars()['name'] }}
```

Comment: this is not a standard way. if I have a more than two level partial view i must add more roots to this data

Comment: In that case, no there is no build-in way to do so, as it is already injected in the 'global'  scope of the blade view. You could, however, still use: {{ get_defined_vars()['name'] }}, if i am not mistaken.

Comment: I updated the answer, maybe you could accept and + ?:)

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 :  What approach you applied ?

Comment: Pretty sure he used the last of 3 options, as after this option, it could be accepted as answer.